# The folder Library/StartUpItems is empty

Tags: macos, filesystem, startup

Under **System Preferences / Users & Groups / Login Items** I can see all of the items that I've selected to launch at startup, but the folder,  `Library/StartUpItems` is empty.

Where can I see these items?

Comment: What do you mean by *these items*? You mean the original file?

Comment: @Thecafremo Perhaps he means the source configuration data? i.e. where does the pref pane load the list of items from?

Comment: Yes, It is my problem. I want get by the Terminal the name of the apps that are launched when i start the mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file the preference pane loads the list of items from is:

`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist`

It is a binary file. You can use Xcode to open it.

For example, if you add iPhoto to your login items:

[image]

your `com.apple.loginitems.plist` will look similar to this:

[image]

Comment: I still have several apps that are being opened automatically on osx startup and are neither on this panel nor on `/Library/StartUpItems` and I can't help to find them

Comment: Items that load which are not in this list are likely to be either LaunchAgents or LaunchDaemons.